# Push notification Led light in android

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

Is there a way to make the led light go off when a push notification has been received from Parse? I'm using the Ionic Framework. I searched everwhere but cant find an answer

Comment: Read this.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_LIGHTS

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I implement this with Ionicframework (cordova).